# Insert or update when product is present using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

main_product table

```
productid outward shopid
    333      2      44//present
    343      4      44//present
    353      5      44//present
    363      1      44//present
    373      2      44//not present
```

min_product table

```
productid outward shopid

333      1      44
343      1      44
353      1      44
363      1      44
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT (A.productid),A.outward, B.productid,B.outward
FROM main_product  A
INNER JOIN min_product B on B.productid=A.product_id
where A.shopid='44' and B.shopid='44'
```

---

my question how can i `INSERT OR UPDATE` in one query using mysql by checking if it is present or not 
 if present update else insert

something like this?

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (key, value)
VALUES  ($newkey, $newvalue)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET     value = $newvalue
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your distinct function in the select statement above?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Procedure` here which would first INSERT along with block of error handler like following and If ERROR of row existence found which is `1062` in MySQL then update would work for you.

EDITED

```
 DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `NAME_SP` $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `NAME_SP`(IN bpin_d int(11))
    READS SQL DATA
begin


DECLARE out_status text;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062
               SET out_status= 'RIN';
INSERT INTO CANDIDATE_POOL(BPIN) VALUES (bpin_d);
IF(out_status <> '') THEN
UPDATE CANDIDATE_POOL u SET u.BPIN = bpin_d;
SET out_status = '';
END IF;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Actually, I did something like that in one of my tasks previously, you only need to write a MySQL Procedure and include above block, hope you are familiar with Procedures. Please let me know If I can assist you in understanding any syntax above.

Comment: i havent used any procedure till now... i am very new to procedure... so please let me know how to use for the above tables

Comment: Give me the schema of your tables

Comment: schema is same as above table

Comment: how does this procedure checks if the product is present or not ...if present it should insert else update the row

Comment: Now only thing that you need to change it is INSERT and corresponding UPDATE and you can pass any number of values to procedure by changing argument list, I used 1 argument here bpin_d which is of int(11) and IN is used to tell that this argument would be given as INPUT.

Comment: If you are still unclear then give me your exact INSERT STATEMENTS, I'll change in the above procedure. BTW stored procedure is called using CALL NAME_SP(no_of_argument);

Comment: You may like to know more about procedures and how to use it
http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/stored-procedures-and-functions.shtml
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html 
if you are satisfied with answer then you can upvote and accept the answer, would help me in increasing my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you won't have a product_id until you add the record to begin with. So you could check your variable first and use that to decide, or you could be able to use `if exists (query...)` like this previously asked question shows [mysql if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840138/mysql-if-exists)