# php, mysqli insert and search based off One value

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to index and rank the list of search terms that have been looked for. I have a separate table in my database with the following info

```
 _ID int Auto_Increment,
 TERM varchar(255),
 RANK int
```

The code I am using to get and display the results is as follows

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$DB_NAME = 'code_storage';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'user';
$DB_PASS = 'pass';


try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` WHERE `CODE_NAME` LIKE :name1 OR `CODE_DESC` LIKE :name2 OR `CODE_TAGS` LIKE :name3 OR `CODE_USAGE` LIKE :name4";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $qpattern = "%" . $q . "%";
    $prep->execute(array(":name1" => $qpattern, ":name2" => $qpattern, ":name3" => $qpattern, ":name4" => $qpattern));
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo    '<div class="panel">';
       printf("Your search for <b>$q</b> returned %d records.\n", $prep->rowCount());
    echo    '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    while ($row = $prep->fetch()) {
    echo '   <div class="row">' . "\n";
    echo '       <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
    echo '              <b><a href="results.php?id=' . $row['_ID'] . '">' . $row['CODE_NAME'] . '</a></b><br/><br/>' . "\n";
    echo '       </div>' . "\n";
    echo '   </div>' . '<br/>' . "\n";
    $db = null;
}

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo    '<div class="panel">';
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo    '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
 ?>
```

I have 1 main question

1. How can I insert the search term that is being pulled from $q into the search table

EDIT: I figured it out I just added this under $query and now it works

```
 $search = "INSERT INTO `search` (`TERM`, `RANK`) VALUES (:search, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `RANK` = `RANK` + 1";
 $sprep =$db->prepare($search);
 $sprep->execute(array(":search" => $q));
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I don't see any code that refers to the `popular` table. You need to post the code that is causing you problems, not the code that works.

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection. You're using mysqli, so why aren't you using prepared queries?

Comment: @ Barmar never tried using prepared queries before, still learning sql and php would love to do this but I wanted to make it work first then I was going to work about learning how to do prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate out the query from your if statement so you can debug it better. Instead of:

```
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
```

I would do:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($result === false){
```

Then I would use a query to either insert the keyword or update the ranking for that keyword in your popular table. See this article: [mysql if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840138/mysql-if-exists). I would do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `popular` (keyword, rank) VALUES ('new keyword', 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rank` = `rank` + 1;
```

Assuming you have the keyword as part of your primary key, then this would insert it if it doesn't already exist, and increase the rank if it does.